# Using Laravel prepareForValidation to add a new property

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am using Laravel's form request class to try and add a new property to my $request via the `prepareForValidation` method.

Basically it takes the 'id' from the URL then uses it to return a relationship on a model.

It works sometimes, but other times i keep getting a `Attempt to read property "transaction" on null` error.

The way I am trying to do this is as follows;

```php
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->merge([
        'transaction_slug' => History::find($this->route('id'))->transaction->transaction_slug,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure, you added `transaction_slug` and its validation rules into the rules array.

```
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'transaction_slug' => 'present',
        // other rules.
    ];
}
```

If you did it already, make sure your query returns not null. If you need null safe, add '?' the way I did.

```
'transaction_slug' => History::find($this->route('id'))?->transaction->transaction_slug,
```

If you need a default value in the case of returning null

```
$history = ;

$this->merge([
    'transaction_slug' => (History::find($this->route('id')) ?? History::first())->transaction->transaction_slug,
]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to check the query for not null in the prepareForValidation method?